# Wordpress Add Read More Tag to a post content (Single.php)

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress custom theme made from scratch including:

- header.php, footer.php, single.php, index.php, functions.php

For Listing the blog list i used index.php with excerpt and read more link to the respective post.

index.php

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="single_excerpt">
                                <h1 class="red_text"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more"><button class="btn btn-default" type="">Read More</button></a>
                            </div>


                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

***This works fine as i expected, but the problem is with single.php as when i want to add read more tag to the post content after the first paragraph,nothing is happened.
please help me to add read more tag from backend to a post content after a first paragraph or as desired and then on single post view only the content will display which is before the tag and after that a read more button and after clicking the button full content will display on the same single view of post.***

single.php

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">

                    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="single_post">
                            <h1 class="red_text"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <div class="post_info">
                                Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> | Posted on: <?php the_date(); ?> | Posted in:<?php the_category(', '); ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else : ?>
                        <div class="post">
                            <h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', 'brightpage'); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>                         

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The more function doesn't work on single.php by default. You should add `global $more; $more = 0;` to your loop:

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()) : 
    while(have_posts())  : 
       the_post(); 
       global $more;
       $more = 0;
       the_content();

       $more = 1;
       the_content('',true,'');
?>
```

Now you have the content with text before the more tag first (`$more = 0`), followed by the text after the more tag (`$more = 1`). With javascript you can show-hide the content onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `the_excerpt();` in the place of `the_content();`

But how you can add read more in single.php file. All read more link for post goes to single.php.
So I suggest to you don't user read more in single.php

Comment: Yes Thanks Ravinder I know that But my client needs that. I think may be someone have solution to the same.